# Proving continuity of a function defined as a series of functions.

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that the real valued function

$$ f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1} \sqrt{x} e^{-n^2 x} $$
is continuous for $x>0$ ? 
I have tried to use the Weierstrass $M$-test to prove the uniform convergence of the series of functions and from the uniform limit theorem conclude the proof, but I can't find the bound to use the $M$-test.
This question is from the book Introduction to Calculus by Kazimierz Kuratowski, and is presented before derivatives and integrals, so I think it's pretended to be solved without that.

Comment: Over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ you have a uniformly convergent series of continuous functions, hence a continuous function by the "$3\varepsilon$-Theorem".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\delta>0$, you can use "$M$-test" on $[\delta, \infty)$: say 
$$
\sqrt x e^{-n^2x}=\sqrt x e^{-n^2x/2}e^{-n^2x/2}\leq C\cdot e^{-n^2\delta/2}\leq 
C\cdot e^{-n\delta/2} ,
$$
where $C=\sup_{x\in[0, \infty)}\sqrt x e^{-x/2}$. So $f$ is continous on every $[\delta, \infty)$.

Comment: Well, but what about delta? What is the relation between delta and x? Maybe is simple, but a can't see what it is.

Comment: If you want to show $f$ is continuous at $x>0$, just choose $\delta>$ so that $\delta <x$...

Comment: I understand that when $x$ is a fixed value, but what would happen if $x$ approaches to $0$? Doesn't that mean that $\delta$ changes with each $x$ and that implies that the series with general term $$C\cdot e^{-n\delta/2}$$ is also a series that need to be uniform convergent?

Comment: The above shows that the series is uniformly convergent on $[\delta, \infty)$, thus the limit is continuous on $[\delta, \infty)$. Since $\delta$ is arbitrary, this shows the limit is continuous on $(0, \infty)$. However, one can prove that this series is not uniformly convergent on $[0, \infty)$.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I was having difficult because my lack of understanding on uniform convergence. Thank you.